# End of line anchor $ throwing error in Hue Pig Editor

Tags: apache-pig, hue

Shen I use the below regex from Hue's pig editor I get an error.

```
REGEX_EXTRACT(cs, '((;|^)u=(.*?)([^0-9a-z-A-Z]|\\$))', 3)
```

It looks like an old issue with prior version of Hue but looks like they have resolved in 3.6 version. 
https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-1958

I am running Hue 3.6 and pig 0.12 but still getting the same error. Can someone help out. Thx.

Error:

> 2014-11-20 08:18:29,282 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext  - Encountered " `<OTHER>` ")=$ "" at line 1, column 1.
>   Was expecting one of:
>       `<EOF>`
>       `<IDENTIFIER>` ...
>       `<COMMENT>` ...
>
> 2014-11-20 08:18:29,289 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.Main  - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. org.apache.pig.tools.parameters.ParseException: Encountered " `<OTHER>` ")=$ "" at line 1, column 1.
>   Was expecting one of:
>       `<EOF>`
>       `<IDENTIFIER>` ...
>       `<COMMENT>` ...

Comment: I get something similar when I had wrong parameters in my pig call, that wasn't related to line 1. This is a bit misleading error msg.

Comment: In response to the previous comment: does the code run without error when you remove the `\\$`)?

Comment: i encountered similar error and it was related to my parameters in the pig call. the error msg is really misleading....